# How to implement private chat in sitefinity?

Tags: sitefinity

I'ld like to implement the private chat among the logged user inside a sitefinity application. Is there any way to implement this? I have looked for various 3rd party but no luck. 
Initially I thought for cute chat but I didn't find any proper documentation for sitefinity.
Please suggest if you have any idea.

Answer (score 1):

First advice - do not look for documentation how to be done in Sitefinity, but rather look how it can be done in a normal html site.

All 3rd party chat apps will require you to put some javascript on the pages of your site. For Sitefinity that could mean putting it on a Page Template level (if you want the chat to be available on all pages using the template) or on a single page level. Then you'll probably need to make some configurations on the chat app, e.g. account name, etc.

You did not specify what you tried and what has failed, so if you are more specific we should be able to help even more.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am new in sitefinity. I know there are lot of 3rd party JS plugin available but I am not sure how they will access the logged in user information and how to configure. Can you please suggest some js plugin name which I can use them. I want the chat to be available on all pages. It'll be great if you provide some hints or link about the configuration.